# TSQL Searching a large indexed database using LIKE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database containing addresses, one address per Row. Contains every address in the UK, so ~28 million rows. One of the columns is 'Street', which I am using to perform searches. I have a non-unique, non-clustered index on this column.

I'm having inconsistencies with search speeds however.

```
select * from Postcodes where Street = 'London Road'
```

Takes ~1s to run.

```
select * from Postcodes where Street like'London Road%'
```

Likewise takes about a second.

```
declare @Street varchar(20) = 'London Road%'
select * from Postcodes where Street like @Street
```

However, this statement, although apparantly identical to the second, takes about 40 seconds to run.

I'm at a complete loss to what is causing this speed difference. Any ideas?

Comment: What datatype is Street please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MSSQLServer can't know in advance what is going to be contained in `@Street` variable, so it can't use an index on `Street` column.

If your statement is:

```
select * from Postcodes where Street = 'London';
select * from Postcodes where Street like 'London Road%';
```

It can used an index on `Street` column because it knows the string starts with `London`.

If your statement is:

```
select * from Postcodes where Street like @VariableName;
```

It can't use the index because with this statement you should be able to do:

```
select * from Postcodes where Street like 'London%';
select * from Postcodes where Street like '%London%';
```

Or any other valid value for `VariableName`. It's a typical problem in precompiled statements.

What you can do is using the string directly, or not using parameters and change your statement to be a dynamic SQL statement in TSQL.

Comment: This isn't the reason. The issue is that it does not use the narrower index as it does not sniff the variable value to determine selectivity. It can still do a range seek for a leading wild card. Just the start and end of the range cover the whole index.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance you will never have leading wildcards and are on SQL Server 2008 you could try

```
declare @Street varchar(20) = 'London Road%'
SELECT * FROM 
Postcodes WITH (FORCESEEK)
where Street like @Street
```